# Removing NaN Values from csv

Tags: csv

I have searched several questions around this topic but have not found and answer that made my code work. I'm a beginner so any help is much appreciated.

I'm using the jupyter notebook and have the following code:

```
import pandas
a = pandas.read_csv("internal_html.csv")
a.dropna(axis="columns", how="any")
a.head(10)
```

I get no error when running the code, but the columns with NaN values still show up.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but you will have to provide much more information since csv is just an term, not even a standard or language

Comment: Sorry, but you will have to provide much more information since csv is just an term, not even a standard or language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reassign the dropna statement back to a.

```
a = a.dropna(axis="columns", how="any")
```

[`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna) *is not* an inplace operation by default.

Or you could:

```
a.dropna(axis="columns", how="any", inplace=True)
```

## Edit to handle empty values in source as mentioned in the comments below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.read_csv("internal_html.csv")
a = a.replace('',np.nan)
a = a.dropna(axis="columns", how="any")
a.head(10)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I added the code but still it's not working. I took a screenshot here https://www.screencast.com/t/ss8YzySsI5nb so you can see what the output is. There is one column "Meta Descriptions 2" that has a lot of NaN values is still showing up. I tried both versions of the code you suggested.

Comment: You need to make sure you null are really NaNs.   Can you paste some lines of you input csv, witv null values.   You might need to replace('', np.nan)  then dropna.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your help. I've pasted some lines below:Meta Description 2 Meta Description 2 Length Meta Description 2 Pixel Width Meta Keyword 1 Meta Keywords 1 Length
 0 0  0
 0 0  0

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your help. Looking at the CSV in excel you can see that the fields are empty: https://www.screencast.com/t/X8VyjFgSU I tried pasting the lines you asked above but they loose their format, not sure if that will be helpful. The screenshot shows that the Meta Keyword 1 column is empty and the Meta Description 2 is empty as well, those are the columns I was trying to remove. If you need more information, please let me know. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, those emptys are not nulls.  You will need to try and replace('',np.nan) import numpy as np first.  Once you see NaN in your dataframe, then the dropna statement will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need replace all " " in csv DataFrame first

```
nan_value = float("NaN")
df_csv.replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)
df_csv.dropna(subset = ["your_column_name"], inplace=True)
```