# How to remove NaN values from csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nan

I have a csv file with the following data:

> ```
> List Of Tables
> DimCurrency
> DimOrganization
> DimProduct
> DimProductCategory
> DimProductSubcategory
> DimPromotion
> ```

Now, I need to read this data and append it to a list.

But when I try to read the data using the following code

```
table_col = ['table']
df1 = pd.read_csv('E:/Tabledata.csv', delimiter=',', names=table_col, header=0)
print(df1)
```

I get the Output as:

> ```
>                        table
> DimCurrency              NaN
> DimOrganization          NaN
> DimProduct               NaN
> DimProductCategory       NaN
> DimProductSubcategory    NaN
> DimPromotion             NaN
> ```

I tried to remove to NaN values using **df.fillna('')** method, it gave me the output:

> ```
>                       table
> DimCurrency
> DimOrganization
> DimProduct
> DimProductCategory
> DimProductSubcategory
> DimPromotion
> ```

And when I try to append this to a list, it returns me:

> ['', '', '', '', '', '']

Any suggestions how can I resolve this?

Comment: Resolve what? What is the problem? What did you expect? [mre]

Comment: I expected the list to be ['DimCurrency', 'DimOrganization', 'DimProduct', 'DimProductCategory', 'DimProductSubcategory','DimPromotion']   and not  ['', '', '', '', '', '']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing NaN Values from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862408/removing-nan-values-from-csv)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to read a single column csv file into a **list**, don' use pandas but pure python:

```
with open('Tabledata.csv') as f:
    for i in range(1): # set here the number of header lines to skip
        next(f)
    out = list(map(str.strip, f.readlines()))
```

output:

```
['DimCurrency',
 'DimOrganization',
 'DimProduct',
 'DimProductCategory',
 'DimProductSubcategory',
 'DimPromotion']
```

Comment: Happy new year @Corralien ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `read_csv`:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('E:/Tabledata.csv', squeeze=True).tolist()
['DimCurrency',
 'DimOrganization',
 'DimProduct',
 'DimProductCategory',
 'DimProductSubcategory',
 'DimPromotion']
```

Or you can simply use:

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('E:/Tabledata.csv').readlines()][1:]
```

Comment: NB. this is ~100 times slower than pure python :p

Answer (score 0):

seems like the content you need is in index column so do this after import data into dataframe.

```
list(df1.index)
```

output:

['DimCurrency', 'DimOrganization', 'DimProduct', 'DimProductCategory', 'DimProductSubcategory', 'DimPromotion']